# how to create add-able metaboxes in wordpress post edit screen?

Tags: posts

Is there anyone who knows how to create add-able multiple metaboxes, easy enough for a user to add a meta box on demand in a single post edit screen ?

Comment: Why would you want users to be able to add metaboxes to the edit screen?

Comment: I have a post that have sections , that have a different style than other data, now I will show those meta-boxes on the front end using a loop or something else, but on the post edit screen , I want to give the user the option to add a new metabox , so that he can create a new section. It will be a new div on the frontend

Comment: Is there any plugin or something , I can use for it. Please tell me

Answer (score 1):

There's several plugins which enable easy creation of meta boxes.

[Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) (ACF) is one of the best and easiest to use for non coders.

Comment: I am already using this plugin and it's really good, but the process is a bit complicated for the users to add a new field to a post, so I want to give as much ease to the users as much I can. This is why I want something like in the post edit screen that can add a meta-box on demand.

Comment: You could create several options and even add help text above the boxes. Its probably the best solution as far as ease of use.

Comment: Is there any option in ACF to have add-able textboxes ?

Comment: Yes there are and its very easy to setup. You will need the code to hook the meta boxes to your custom field.

Comment: Well, very good then, So where can I find that code @ Brad

Answer (score -1):

I'm using page builder now and that solves everything, Visual Composer is the ultimate plugin for this